# django filter fields + custom Q field

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use regular filter fields with multi search field.
If I put just

```
fields = [`q`]
```

or

```
fields = {
    'model': ['icontains'],
    'type' : ['icontains'],
}
```

then it works but if I try to use them together, it doesn't. How do I make this work so I can use both ['q'] and model, type filter together?

filter.py

```
class CustomFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='custom_search_filter',label="Title & Tag Search")

    class Meta:
        model = CustomModel
        fields = {
            'model': ['icontains'],
            'type' : ['icontains'],
            ['q']
        }

    def custom_search_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=value) | Q(tag__icontains=value)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a declaratively declared filter in `Meta` at all. `Meta` is a way to let filter initialization create the boilerplate for the common cases.

Try just deleting `['q']`, i.e.

```
fields = {
        'model': ['icontains'],
        'type' : ['icontains'],
    }
```

Comment: I already know deleting ['q'] works. I am looking for a way to use [`q`] with existing single field filters.